# Whats the difference between these two jquery functions?

Tags: html, jquery, dom

Both of them extract text from the first td. Does one have more advantage than the other ?

```
alert($(this).children("td:first-child").text());
```

and

```
alert($(this).closest("tr").find("td:first-child").text());
```

Jquery

```
$("#table").on("click", '.serviceCode', function(){
            alert($(this).attr('id'));
             alert($(this).closest("tr").find("td:first-child").text());
        });
```

Html

```
    <div id="table">
<tr id="dsd class="serviceCode"><td>Item 1</td><td>2.00</td></tr>
</div>
```

Comment: The result would be exactly the same assuming the HTML stays exactly like this. `$(this).closest("tr")` is going to be the same as `$(this)` here because `this` is the `<tr>` element so `closest` will just find itself - it starts from the current node and goes up. However, if there is any other node with a `serviceCode` class, then you might not get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation at https://api.jquery.com/children/ has a very clear and direct explanation of the difference:

> The .children() method differs from .find() in that .children() only travels a single level down the DOM tree while .find() can traverse down multiple levels to select descendant elements (grandchildren, etc.) as well.

I would normally expect that searching through only the first level of descendants would be much more efficient. (Although in individual cases, if that's the lowest level of the DOM anyway it may not have any advantage. It would depend on the exact implementation.) However in a modern browser you would be unlikely to see any noticeable difference in performance unless the DOM tree being searched is very large.

Also, the closest() function is redundant in this case because it starts searching from the current node ("this") and goes upwards, so it will simply find itself and stop. So in theory removing this should also give you a performance boost but again it's unlikely to be noticeable. The main reason to remove it is readability of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Basically Both find() and children() methods are used to filter the child of the matched elements,

**Find()** find() method is used to search the more than one level down the tree (DOM tree)

**Children()**
Children() method is used to find a single level down the tree.

**Note**
children() method executes faster than find() method.